# How to convert millisecond to second

Tags: android

I have following code in my service.

```
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000 * 3, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            intentDSU.putExtra("remaind", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l));
            sendBroadcast(intentDSU);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            postHandler();

            intentDSU.putExtra("remaind", 0);
            sendBroadcast(intentDSU);

            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
```

That's work fine, but when i try convert seconds to minutes and remaind of seconds on my activity

```
private void updateGUI(Intent intent){
    if(intent.getExtras() != null){
        long remaind = intent.getLongExtra("remaind", 0);
        if(remaind == 0){
            onRefresh();
        }

        long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(remaind) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(remaind)* 60);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(remaind) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(remaind) *60);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timer);
        if(menuItem != null){
            if(minutes > 0){
                menuItem.setTitle(String.format("%o min.", minutes));
            }
            else {
                menuItem.setTitle(String.format("%o sec.", seconds));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I become notice unusual results, seconds will start 73 instead 60. I haven't idea, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're code is correct, I quess you get problem in String.format("%o min.", minutes) and here String.format("%o sec.", seconds).

Try to use this.

```
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_timer);
    if(menuItem != null){
        if(minutes > 0){
            menuItem.setTitle(String.format("%s min.", Long.toString(minutes)));
        }
        else {
            menuItem.setTitle(String.format("%s sec.", Long.toString(seconds)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 long sec=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(passmillitimer);
```